# Python and Kotlin applications socket sync issue

Tags: python, kotlin, synchronization, client-server

I am writing an app on Kotlin that uses Python backend server and I seem to have some trouble connecting them together.

On python I use

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
def handle_connection(c):
    amount = int(c.recv(2048).decode("utf8"))
    for i in range(amount):
        print(c.recv(2048).decode("utf8"))
class FileReceiver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 7557))
            self.socket.listen()
            while True:
                c, a = self.socket.accept()
                thr = Thread(target=handle_connection, args=(c,))
                thr.run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.socket.detach()
            self.socket.close()

fr = FileReceiver()
fr.run()
```

to receive data from client.
And on Kotlin I use

```
val socket = Socket(server_ip, server_port)
val input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))
val out = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())
out.write("10")
out.flush()
for (i in 1..10)
{
    out.write("A")
    out.flush()
}
```

to send the data.
Using this code results in server receiving only one message with all the A's, but I am trying to get it to receive all of them in separate messages within the loop.
I am not the best programmer so any help regarding this code will be appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `SOCK_STREAM` suggests, you don't really send/receive messages here, but a stream of bytes. TCP, which you use here, does not understand messages. Sending `"AAAAA"` once and sending `"A"` five times is almost the same.

If you need to send messages and receive them as they were sent, you have to introduce some kind of a protocol on top of TCP. This protocol will encode messages on one side and decode them on the receiving side.

The easiest way to implement this manually is to send e.g. 2 bytes with the size of the message and then the message itself. On receiving side you first read 2 bytes and then read the required number of bytes to decode a full message. It can be implemented like this:

**Kotlin/client**

```kotlin
fun main() {
    ...

    val out = DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
    out.writeMsg("10".toByteArray())
    for (i in 1..10)
    {
        out.writeMsg("A".toByteArray())
    }
}

fun DataOutputStream.writeMsg(msg: ByteArray) {
    require(msg.size.toUShort() <= UShort.MAX_VALUE)
    writeShort(msg.size)
    write(msg)
}
```

**Python/server**

```py
def recvall(sock, size):
    result = bytearray()
    while len(result) < size:
        result.extend(sock.recv(size - len(result)))
    return result

def recvmsg(sock):
    size = struct.unpack('>H', recvall(sock, 2))[0]
    return recvall(sock, size)
    

def handle_connection(c):
    amount = int(recvmsg(c).decode("utf8"))
    for i in range(amount):
        print(recvmsg(c).decode("utf8"))
```

Note this code is probably not production-ready. It should be tested for erroneous scenarios like network disconnections, etc.

You could also try to use existing protocols/libraries that provide message-based networking. One such library is [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/) - it is multi-language, relatively simple and easy to use. Be warned though that it is truly purely message-based, so it may sometimes seem  weird to use. For example, it works in connection-less fashion, it hides network connections from its user. Which is good, because we don't need to accept connections, it automatically reconnects, we can `connect` before `bind`/`listen`, etc. On the other hand, it does not provide us with info on connected clients, it does not notify us about disconnections and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you suggest a library that I can use both for Kotlin and Python?

Comment: I updated my answer to provide some examples. And yes, you can use ZeroMQ in both Python and Kotlin. Remember that you can use any Java library in Kotlin. I suggest choosing JeroMQ implementation if you are interested. However... on second thought, ZeroMQ may not be the best idea. It is really great and makes networking super easy, but on the other hand it introduces several concepts that may seem weird and has to be learnt. It may not be good as a starting point, it could be better to first understand networking itself and then jump to frameworks like ZeroMQ.